# Pushing avro file to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

I have an existing avro file and I want to push the file data into kafka but it's not working

```
/usr/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list test:9092 --topic test < part-m-00000.avro
```

Thanks

Comment: Not clear what data you're expecting in the topic, but Avro files aren't new-line delimited and the schema isn't on every line, so even if this worked, the consumer deserializer would have a very difficult time reading that data

Answer (score 7):

You need to first download the avro-tools JAR file

Then get the schema from the file

```
java -jar avro-tools.jar getschema part-m-00000.avro > schema.avsc
```

Then install `jq` because it'll help in a minute format that schema file

Next, Avro messages in Kafka ideally should not contain the schema for every single record, so it would improve your overall topic throughput and network usage if you installed the Avro Schema Registry from Confluent (or the one from Hortonworks, but I've yet to try it).

After that's working, and you have the rest of the Confluent Platform downloaded, there's a script for producing Avro data, but to use it, you need JSON records from the Avro file. Use avro-tools again to get it

```
java -jar avro-tools.jar tojson part-m-00000.avro > records.json
```

*Note* - this output file will be significantly larger than the Avro file

Now, you're able to produce using the schema, which will be sent to the registry, and binary avro data into the topic, which is converted from applying the schema onto JSON records

```
bin/kafka-avro-console-producer \
         --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test \
        --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 \
         --property value.schema="'$(jq -r tostring schema.avsc)'" < records.json
```

*Note*: Run `jq -r tostring schema.avsc` before this command, make sure it's an not an escaped JSON string

---

If that is output JSON file is too large, you might also be able to stream the avro-tools output into the producer

Replace

```
< records.json
```

With

```
< $(java -jar avro-tools.jar tojson part-m-00000.avro)
```

---

Alternative solutions would include reading the Avro files in Spark, then forwarding those records to Kafka

Comment: Minor correction to an otherwise very helpful answer:
`--property schema-registry.url=http://localhost:8081`  
should be  
`--property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081`

Comment: I found out your schema cannot contain any equal signs. It's a bug fixed in Kafka 2.0

Answer (score 1):

If you want to publish Avro Messages, you can try kafka-avro-console-producer.

```
$ ./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer \
             --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test \
             --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}]}'  < avrofile.avro
```

It is part of confluent open source package
Please refer the more details here. https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/quickstart.html

*P.S. Could not find the commands in latest version*

Comment: This won't work... Avro console consumer wants to read JSON formatted messages that match the value schema. Also, probably shouldn't link to old documentation